# I'm trying to build the vst3 sdk example plugins, but get an error on 32 bit linux mint 19

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, sdk

Here's the output, I'm not really sure what it means and what to do about it.

I'm on linux mint 19, 32 bit

Note:
This is not the full output due to the ridiculous rule about posting mostly code. I'm really not sure what else to add, so at this point this is just padding. It appears I'm going to have to do a lot of it. What an utterly ridiculous rule to need to have a 1:1 ratio to an error output, that makes absolutely no sense.

````
In file included from /home/user/Downloads/VST_SDK/VST3_SDK/public.sdk/source/vst/testsuite/vststructsizecheck.h:54:0,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/VST_SDK/VST3_SDK/public.sdk/samples/vst-hosting/validator/source/validator.cpp:41:
/home/user/Downloads/VST_SDK/VST3_SDK/public.sdk/source/vst/testsuite/vststructsizecheck.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr Steinberg::Vst::{anonymous}::sizeofCheckProcessSetup<ProcessSetup, w, x, y, z>::sizeofCheckProcessSetup() [with ProcessSetup = Steinberg::Vst::ProcessSetup; unsigned int w = 24; unsigned int x = 20; unsigned int y = 24; unsigned int z = 24]’:
/home/user/Downloads/VST_SDK/VST3_SDK/public.sdk/source/vst/testsuite/vststructsizecheck.h:76:1:   required from here
/home/user/Downloads/VST_SDK/VST3_SDK/pluginterfaces/base/typesizecheck.h:30:4: error: static assertion failed: Struct sizeof error: ProcessSetup
    static_assert (Operator (Type) ==                                                      \
    ^
/home/user/Downloads/VST_SDK/VST3_SDK/pluginterfaces/base/typesizecheck.h:44:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SMTG_TYPE_STATIC_CHECK’
  SMTG_TYPE_STATIC_CHECK (sizeof, Type, Platform64Size, MacOS32Size, Win32Size, Linux32Size)
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/Downloads/VST_SDK/VST3_SDK/public.sdk/source/vst/testsuite/vststructsizecheck.h:76:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘SMTG_TYPE_SIZE_CHECK’
 SMTG_TYPE_SIZE_CHECK (ProcessSetup, 24, 20, 24, 24)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/Downloads/VST_SDK/VST3_SDK/public.sdk/source/vst/testsuite/vststructsizecheck.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr Steinberg::Vst::{anonymous}::sizeofCheckAudioBusBuffers<AudioBusBuffers, w, x, y, z>::sizeofCheckAudioBusBuffers() [with AudioBusBuffers = Steinberg::Vst::AudioBusBuffers; unsigned int w = 24; unsigned int x = 16; unsigned int y = 24; unsigned int z = 24]’:
/home/user/Downloads/VST_SDK/VST3_SDK/public.sdk/source/vst/testsuite/vststructsizecheck.h:77:1:   required from here
/home/user/Downloads/VST_SDK/VST3_SDK/pluginterfaces/base/typesizecheck.h:30:4: error: static assertion failed: Struct sizeof error: AudioBusBuffers
    static_assert (Operator (Type) ==                                                      \
    ^
/home/user/Downloads/VST_SDK/VST3_SDK/pluginterfaces/base/typesizecheck.h:44:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SMTG_TYPE_STATIC_CHECK’
  SMTG_TYPE_STATIC_CHECK (sizeof, Type, Platform64Size, MacOS32Size, Win32Size, Linux32Size)
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

make[2]: *** [public.sdk/samples/vst-hosting/validator/CMakeFiles/validator.dir/source/validator.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1235: recipe for target 'public.sdk/samples/vst-hosting/validator/CMakeFiles/validator.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [public.sdk/samples/vst-hosting/validator/CMakeFiles/validator.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2```
````

Comment: Is the VST 3.x SDK available for linux?

Comment: Yes, there are instructions on the GitHub page for building on linux.

Comment: I see. Good luck ( you will need it).

Comment: Why do I need luck?

Comment: Because no one works with Linux when pro audio/video is the case.